# How to fix struct.unpack long issue between py3.8.0 and py3.7.3?

Tags: python-3.x, struct

I'm struggling in python 3.8.0 to unpack the long as specified in the example. Is there a workaround or syntax change that I don't understand?

```
    test=b'\x02\x00\x00\x00'
```

In python 3.7.3 (windows)

```
    struct.calcsize('l')
    struct.unpack('l',test)
```

produces

```
    4
    (2,)
```

but in python 3.8.0 (linux) it returns

```
     8
```

and

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Python version issue; it's a platform issue.

On x86-64:

- Windows (MSVC) `long` is usually 4 bytes
- Linux (GCC) `long` is usually 8 bytes